# cv2 error in face detection

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote a program that will import an image for facial recognition and analysis, however, I am receiving this error

```
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.error: /home/piwheels/opencv-
    python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:10638: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

This is the main part of the code, which will import the image:

```
frame = vs.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
faces = faceDetector(gray, 0)

for (i, face) in enumerate(faces):

    facialLandmarks = facialLandmarkPredictor(gray, face)
    facialLandmarks = face_utils.shape_to_np(facialLandmarks)

    (x, y, w, h) = face_utils.rect_to_bb(face)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, '#{}'.format(i+1), (x, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    landmarksArray = realTimeFacialLandmarks.getDistance(facialLandmarks)
    realTimeFacialLandmarks.facialPointJson(t,landmarksArray)

    for (a, b) in facialLandmarks:
        cv2.circle(frame, (a, b), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
```

I cannot rectify the error in this file, can someone please point out the mistake in this?

Comment: When you signed up, you were encouraged to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). #1: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." I suggest to edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue of actually capturing the frame from the video source. Most likely, you are sending a bad or empty image to `cv2.cvtColor`. I would suggest looking into some other info about what is going on, such as checking the return value of `vs.isOpened()` (true if successfully opened), as well as image properties of the frame that you get back, like `frame.shape`, which should look like `(640, 480, 3)`